# Multiple expression RegEx in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

**Note**: I have next to zero experience with Ansible.

I need to be able to conditionally modify the configuration of a Kubernetes cluster control plane service. To do this I need to be able to find a specific piece of information in the file and if its value matches a specific pattern, change the value to something else.

To illustrate, consider the following YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    component: kube-controller-manager
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
...
```

In this scenario, the line I'm interested in is the line containing `--bind-address`. If that field's value is "127.0.0.1", it needs to be changed to "0.0.0.0". If it's already "0.0.0.0", nothing needs to be done. (I could also approach it from the point of view of: if its *not* "0.0.0.0" then it needs to change to that.)

The initial thought that comes to mind is: just search for "`--bind-address=127.0.0.1`" and replace it with "`--bind-address=0.0.0.0`". Simple enough, eh? No, not that simple. What if, for some reason, there is another piece of configuration in this file that *also* matches that pattern? Which one is the right one?

The only way I can think of to ensure I find the right text to change, is a multiple expression RegEx match. Something along the lines of:

- find `spec:`
- if found, find `containers:` "within" or "under" `spec:`
- if found, find `- command:` "within" or "under" `containers:` (Note: there can be more than one "command")
- if found, find `- kube-controller-manager` "within" or "under" `- command:`
- if found, find `- --bind-address` "within" or "under" `- kube-controller-manager`
- if found, get the value after the `=`
- if `127.0.0.1` change it to `0.0.0.0`, otherwise do nothing

How could I write an Ansible playbook to perform these steps, in sequence and only if each step returns true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data from the file into a dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: conf.yml
        name: conf
```

gives

```yaml
  conf:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: kube-controller-manager
        tier: control-plane
      name: kube-controller-manager
      namespace: kube-system
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - kube-controller-manager
        - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
        - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
        - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Update the containers

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        containers: []
    - set_fact:
        containers: "{{ containers +
                        (update_candidate is all)|ternary([_item], [item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ conf.spec.containers|d([]) }}"
      vars:
        update_candidate:
          - item is contains 'command'
          - item.command is contains 'kube-controller-manager'
          - item.command|select('match', '--bind-address')|length > 0
        update: "{{ item.command|map('regex_replace',
                                     '--bind-address=127.0.0.1',
                                     '--bind-address=0.0.0.0') }}"
        _item: "{{ item|combine({'command': update}) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Update *conf*

```yaml
  conf_update: "{{ conf|combine({'spec': spec}) }}"
  spec: "{{ conf.spec|combine({'containers': containers}) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  spec:
    containers:
    - command:
      - kube-controller-manager
      - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      - --bind-address=0.0.0.0

  conf_update:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: kube-controller-manager
        tier: control-plane
      name: kube-controller-manager
      namespace: kube-system
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - kube-controller-manager
        - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
        - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
        - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Write the update to the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/conf.yml
        content: |
          {{ conf_update|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/conf.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    component: kube-controller-manager
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    conf_update: "{{ conf|combine({'spec': spec}) }}"
    spec: "{{ conf.spec|combine({'containers': containers}) }}"

  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: conf.yml
        name: conf
    - debug:
        var: conf

    - set_fact:
        containers: []
    - set_fact:
        containers: "{{ containers +
                        (update_candidate is all)|ternary([_item], [item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ conf.spec.containers|d([]) }}"
      vars:
        update_candidate:
          - item is contains 'command'
          - item.command is contains 'kube-controller-manager'
          - item.command|select('match', '--bind-address')|length > 0
        update: "{{ item.command|map('regex_replace',
                                     '--bind-address=127.0.0.1',
                                     '--bind-address=0.0.0.0') }}"
        _item: "{{ item|combine({'command': update}) }}"

    - debug:
        var: containers
    - debug:
        var: spec
    - debug:
        var: conf_update

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/conf.yml
        content: |
          {{ conf_update|to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. It will take some time for me to analyze and understand this. I do see bits and pieces of what you're doing, though.

Comment: It seems like some phrases are out of order? For example, in the second `set_fact` an item named `update_candidate` appears to be used/specified before the `vars` phrase that defines it. Is this just the Ansible syntax that I don't yet understand?

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on good sources of tutorials for Ansible?

Comment: *vars* in a task means these variables exist in the scope of this task only. There is no order. A variable is evaluated at the last moment when it is used. See [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Comment: See [Tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#tests).